# Google recaptcha : How to access the response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, recaptcha

For the HTML part, I have google REcaptcha widget like below

```
<form id="test" action="?" method="POST>

        <div style="width: 298px!important;margin-left:-1px;" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lf2_Q4UAAAAAOf0NDqKDpEHncrFuKBRuw5bJfSO"></div>

     <input type="submit" type="button" id="signin-button" class="signin-button" value="Login" />
      </form>
```

And by the time when the user clicks on the submit button, it should run a little Ajax function and see if the result is true then the page should be redirected somewhere else otherwise it should remain the same and display an error message.

I have my ajax code below, I am nearly finished the function but I have no idea how may I get the response value for the field.

```
 $("#signinform").on('submit', function(e) {

                var ReCaptchaDetail = {
                        secret: "6Lf2_Q4UAAAAAOf0NDqKDpEHncrFuKBRuw5bJfSO",
                        response : $("#recaptcha-token").attr("value"),
                        //can't get the response value
                        //remoteip: , //optional

                    };

                console.log(ReCaptchaDetail)

                $.ajax({
                        url: 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',//getting the goggle api
                        data: JSON.stringify(ReCaptchaDetail),
                        type: 'POST',
                         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", //must decode
                         dataType: "json", //must define data type

                         success: function(data){ 

                            console.log(data);

                         }
                });
```